# Spark RDDs join operation with lists

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, rdd

I have the following RDDs:

```
JavaPairRDD<List<String>, String> firstRDD = ...
firstRDD.foreach(row -> System.out.println(row._1() + ", " + row._2()));
// [Man, Parent], Father

JavaPairRDD<List<String>, String> secondRDD = ...
secondRDD.foreach(row -> System.out.println(row._1() + ", " + row._2()));
// [Man, Parent, Father], Person
```

I want to perform an inner join, so that one row is equals to another row **if the left key is IN (*i.e.*, sublist of) the right key** (in the former example, `[Man, Parent]` is in `[Man, Parent, Father]`).

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: get on to scala and dataframes is my advice. life is a hell of a lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RDDs (and also for JavaPairRDDs) the [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#join-org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD-) operation(s) can only check for exactly matching keys.

Therefore we have to transform the RDDs into Dataframes:

```java
public static Dataset<Row> toDataframe(SparkSession spark, JavaPairRDD<List<String>, String> rdd) {
    JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD1 = rdd.map(tuple -> {
        Seq<String> key = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(tuple._1().iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
        return RowFactory.create(key, tuple._2());
    });
    StructType st = new StructType()
            .add(new StructField("key", DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType), true, new MetadataBuilder().build()))
            .add(new StructField("value", DataTypes.StringType, true, new MetadataBuilder().build()));
    return spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD1, st);
}
```

For the join criteria, we need a UDF to check if one array is part of the other. If the order of the elements is not important, [array_intersect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#array_intersect-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) could also be used.

```java
UserDefinedFunction contains = functions.udf((Seq<String> a, Seq<String> b) -> b.containsSlice(a), DataTypes.BooleanType);
```

Putting these two elements together, we get

```java
Dataset<Row> df1 = toDataframe(spark, firstRDD);
Dataset<Row> df2 = toDataframe(spark, secondRDD);
Dataset<Row> result = df1.join(df2,contains.apply(df1.col("key"), df2.col("key")));
```

With the input data

```
firstRDD        secondRDD
+------+-----+  +------------+-----+
|   key|value|  |         key|value|
+------+-----+  +------------+-----+
|[a, b]|    A|  |   [a, b, c]|    C|
|[b, a]|    B|  |[a, b, c, d]|    D|
+------+-----+  +------------+-----+
```

we get

```
+------+-----+------------+-----+
|   key|value|         key|value|
+------+-----+------------+-----+
|[a, b]|    A|   [a, b, c]|    C|
|[a, b]|    A|[a, b, c, d]|    D|
+------+-----+------------+-----+
```

Please not that using an UDF as join criteria might not be the [fastest option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32952938/2129801).